# Secant method versus tangent method

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, newton-raphson, secant

I am considering the tangent method and the secant method as ways to approximate roots of functions, in particular function $5\cos(x-e^{8x})-x$. How can I find the minimum number of iterations $k$, such that for $x_k$ which is the $k$th approximation we have $|f(x_k)| < 10^{−10}$?

Comment: $k$ will depend on the particular function

Comment: @Henry I added my function

Comment: In general, for the tangent and secant methods, there isn't a formula, like there is for the binary search method, showing you how many iterations you'll need in advance.

Comment: is there a way to find out for this one? @AdrianKeister

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. The problem here is that the derivative is sometimes zero. Since the derivative shows up in the denominator of Newton's method, you can sometimes get a near-divide-by-zero, which throws off the iteration count drastically. It doesn't just depend on the function, it also depends on the choice of initial values - it can even be highly dependent on the choice of initial value. If you want a more stable algorithm, binary search is very nice, and is especially attractive when your derivative cross the $x$ axis as often as yours does.

Comment: @AdrianKeister makes sense, thank you

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: I thought of smth else: what if we take $x_0 \in \{-1,0,1,2,\ldots,8\}$ and for the secant also $x_1 = x_0 + 10^{-6}$. In this case maybe we can say something? @AdrianKeister

Comment: You just can't guarantee that any of the values you plug into the RHS of the secant or Newton-Raphson method aren't going to cause it to explode.